# android : editing file in first method, using edited file in second method

Tags: java, android

I have a file and using my first method, I want to edit some text in it. 
After that using second method I want to read from my file and show it.

I created a button like this:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        firstMethod();
        secondMethod();
    }
});
```

After pressing the button, first method works perfectly. Second method reads the old content of the file (from before being edited by first method)

Pressed the button for second time, I see that my file is edited right.

Comment: Please click the "Edit" link below your question and add the code for the firstMethod and second Method so that we can see what is actually happening.

Comment: @CindyMeister it depends on methods?...

Comment: Yes, it does. Most probably you don't close/flush the file in the first method and so the second method sees the wrong file.